# How to show searchview's suggestion list programmatically

Tags: android, searchview

I want the suggestions on searchview to be visible in the initial state of my application, I tried `mSearchView.requestFocus();` `mSearchView.performClick();` They didn't work. I have to click on the searchview manually to bring up the dropdown list. I set up suggestions following this guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html and I'm using searchview from support library.

Comment: you cannot do that, you have to click on it first

Comment: there must be a way, no?

Comment: ok i might be wrong: try `expandActionView`

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you. I also had to set `showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"` in menu.xml to get `expandActionView` working